# How to setup emulator for Galaxy S4 which don't have android system bar inside it at bottom?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I would like to know how to setup emulator for Galaxy S4 which don't have android system bar at bottom of screen,instead they have buttons for them.Without the system bar it tend take more than 25 dp of screen height.Please help me to up an emulator for this.Thanks a lot.